# Make background image cover div by stretching, not maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: css, sass, background-image

How do I make a background image cover the div by stretching, so the whole image is always visible, not like background-size: cover, where the aspect ratio does not change?

It's not a fixed width, it has to be responsive.

```
div {
  position: relative;

  &:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image: url('/something.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
 }
}
```

I tried background-size: 100% 100%, also tried with img tag.

Thank you!

Comment: `background-size: auto` ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size

Comment: Remove the space in `content: ""` and replace `background-position: 0 0;` with `background-position: center center;`

Comment: Thank you! There was a problem in the actual svg, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was also a problem in the actual svg.
The solution below:

```
div {
  position: relative;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

I removed the height and width parameters from my svg and also added: preserveAspectRatio="none"

Answer (score 0):

If Stretching is not an issue then for img tag

```
<style>
img{
  /*
  Control only width or height if u don't want it to stretch. If that's not a problem then you can
  control both of it */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>

<img src="/something.svg" />
```

For background images :

```
<style>
div{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:url("/something.svg");
background-size:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>

<div></div>
```